# How to build a custom command with options

Tags: mac, command-line, git

I want to make a command on my Mac to do the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m CUSTOM_COMMEND_BY_COMMAND
git push
cap deploy
```

I seem to be calling those very often. I was wondering what's the best way to build a command such as:

```
qwik_dply -m "fixed a big"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using a custom bash function. Add that to your `.bash_profile`:

```
function qwik_dply {
    local msg=$1
    if [ -z "$msg" ] ; then
        msg="No message"
    fi
    git add .
    git commit -m "$msg"
    git push
    cap deploy
}
```

Call from bash using `qwik_dply "Some text"`

---

Alternatively, make it a proper script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
msg=$1
if [ -z "$msg" ] ; then
    echo "Usage: qwik_dply <message>"
    exit 1
fi
git add .
git commit -m "$msg"
git push
cap deploy
```

Save as `qwik_dply.sh`, run `chmod ugo+x qwik_dply.sh` and `mv` it to `/usr/bin` or any other directory on your `$PATH`.

Then, run using `qwik_dply.sh "Some message"`. You could remove the file name extension, of course.