# Creating Mac OS terminal shortcuts

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build a custom command with options](https://superuser.com/questions/283874/how-to-build-a-custom-command-with-options)

I want to create a terminal short that takes me to a deeply-nested folder.  For example, I just want to type in "star" every time I open the terminal to take me to cd source/alpha/beta/star.

I find it hard to believe this question hasn't been asked, but I can assure you haven't found the exact step-by-step solution.  If you could let me know how to, or just point me to an existing answer, I'd appreciate.

Comment: ... unless someone remembers that, unlike in that case, aliases aren't the only possible answer here, and tells the poor questioner about the `CDPATH` variable.  (-:

Answer (score 5):

You need to look at [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) [aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29).

Try adding the following to either your `.profile` or `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
alias star='cd source/alpha/beta/star'
```

Any command-line editor (eg `vi` or `emacs`) will work, as would any text editor for the Mac. Aliases work on all Unix-like environments (SunOS, Mac OS X, Linux, AIX, etc).

Then exit [Terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Terminal), and when you restart, it should be there. (Alternatively, you can source the script file, but I've found restarting `bash` to be better.)

Comment: Can you please point out where .profile, .bashrc and .bash_profile are located? Thanks

Comment: @PaulMason - they're where they are in any *nix-like environment: in your home directory when you open your console.

Answer (score 3):

You want to make aliases. Here's an easy way to make an alias without having to open up the .bashrc file. Just save this script into a file called **mkalias** and then move it to your usr binary directory (I believe that is `~/bin` for OSX). Then run `chmod +x mkalias` on the file. Now whenever you want to create an alias you just type: `mkalias myalias='my commands'`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# path to .bashrc, .zshrc, etc.
export RC='~/.bashrc'

if [ `expr index "${1:-0}i" =` == 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: mkalias ALIAS=EXPRESSION
Makes alias permanent by writing to .bash_aliases contained in home directory."
else
    # Export alias
    echo 'alias '$1 >> $RC
fi
```

and to answer your question now, just type:

```
alias star='cd /path/where/you/want/to/go'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this applescript on for size:

```
do shell script "open -a Terminal.app"
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd /path/to/my/directory"
end tell
```

That should open a Terminal for you and take you into your directory. You can shortcut it to your desktop, or maybe create a shortcut for it.

Answer (score 0):

Shell scripts are the normal way to get things done, but `cd` only affects the current shell and shell scripts invoke a new subshell in order to run. You will need to create an **alias** in order to affect the current shell.

```
alias star="cd source/alpha/beta/star"
```

If you add that line to `~/.bashrc` then it should normally be available whenever you open the terminal.

Comment: how to you add to ~/.bashrc?

Comment: Open it in a text editor. It's a plain text file.

Comment: The . indicates that the file is hidden, so you can enable hidden files in your finder, or ls -a to see what's there. Edit as any other text file.