# How to create terminal shortcut to desktop?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, alias

I did find this answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/299092/creating-mac-os-terminal-shortcuts). However could not get it to work with my current setup :(

For example, when I start up iTerm currently it's been set to a specific direction (another developer did that) it's deep inside a folder inside of my Applications folder.

Basically I have `cd ..` 4 times in order to get to the Applications / Network / Users dir... then once I'm there I have to cd into my `Users > leongaban > and finally Desktop`

How would you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah I need to use Terminal more often.. found my older question here:
[How do I create a terminal shortcut to this path?](https://superuser.com/questions/606308/how-do-i-create-a-terminal-shortcut-to-this-path)

Also found out that I can just do:

```
cd ~
cd Desktop/
open .
```